# Why isn't my input box responsive?

Tags: html, css, input, responsive-design

http://jsfiddle.net/4ws3L6kn/1/

I'm curious why doesn't it responsive? what did I do wrong?

```
<div id="DIV_1">
    <div id="DIV_2">
        <div id="DIV_3">

            <button id="BUTTON_4">
                <span id="SPAN_5"></span>
            </button> 
            <button id="BUTTON_6">
                <span id="SPAN_7"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your message..." id="INPUT_8" />
        <div id="DIV_9">

            <button id="BUTTON_10">
                Send
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's just some HTML. Generally you would want to write some CSS in order to make something responsive.

Comment: You hardcoded width values in px. You probably want some % values.

Comment: Why would it be responsive? Do you mean responsive as in: the size of the input should change dynamically with the size of the window? The CSS in your jsfiddle determines static widths, so you're literally telling it not to be responsive. As a side note, there seems to be a lot of unnecessary CSS in there.

Comment: `#INPUT_8 {width: 650px;}` <--- that's why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try chanhe your input style with this

## INPUT_8 {width: 90%;}